# Azure. Adding a certificate from GoDaddy CA to an Azure hosted website

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

[I am following instructions from this website on how to add a certificate to my azure hosted website](https://yaplex.com/blog/ssl-domain-certificate-azure-website-from-godaddy). That seems to be the most common method people use to add https to their azure website

I created a  CSR in IIS manager and have it fulfilled by the CA(Godaddy in this case) I get a .crt and a .p7b. I hit "Complete Certificate Request" in IIS manager and the cert gets added. From the added certificate I'm supposed to export it as a .PFX but IIS manager has no option to export.
[image: IIS Manager]
Instead all i see is renew. If I try to do this through MMC exporting the certificate as a .pfx is just grayed out.

What am I Doing wrong?

Comment: try this https://superuser.com/questions/1098614/how-can-i-export-a-certificate-from-mmc-as-a-pfx-file

Answer (score 0):

On the IIS Machine that you created the certificate on, you will need to connect to the Local Computer Certificate manager and export the certificate from there.

Steps:

Start -> Run -> MMC

Once the MMC is up to go

File -> Add/Remove Snapin..

Select the Certificate Snap-in and follow prompts to added local computer.

[Adding Local computer Certificate Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK1FB.png)

Once Local Computer certificate manager has been added, navigate to the personal certificate store.  You should see the certificate you created with a key next to it indicating its a certificate with private key.

[Certificate with private key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8dBs.png)

From that section you should be able to export certificate.

Hope this helps.